# Disable/Enable pass-through for UWP MediaPlayerElement

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

VLC and Exoplayer has the ability to Enable/Disable passthrough to the receiver. If you have Dolby Digital and passthrough is enabled then you get Dolby Digital, if you have it disabled will come out as PCM.

My question is for UWP MediaPlayerElement. Right now it will only enable passthrough but I want the option to disable it. I am looking at mediaPlayer.AddAudioEffect and seeing if that will give me the ability to do so but can't find a good example.

Edit 1: Removed confusing code as just want to disable passthrough

Comment: From your description, it's not very clear. Do you want to disable passthrough or add audioEffects?

Comment: Disable pass through, just wondering the steps to take

Comment: To follow up it is also DRM protected content. I can play it fine but tryng to add anything to it fails. So is there a way to Disable passthrough on Playready content?

Comment: You can change the audio track that you want to hear in MeidaPlayer by changing the AudioTracks property of a MediaPlaybackItem. I'm not sure if you can actually select Dolby or PCM using this mechanism. 

You won't be able to add an audio effect if the content is DRM protected. DRM goes through the PMP and would require that the audio effect be explicitly signed to allow it to function in the context of the PMP.